# How to categorised linux command returncode/exitcode

Tags: linux, terminal

I am not much into bash scripting, but do return code have categories??

- What are they?
- how they are categorised?

Thank you

Comment: There are only two categories (0 = success, everything else = failure). Some programs, like bash or xargs have special exit codes for some specific conditions (eg. 127 = command not found in a shell). But that's NOT something general, and is NOT enforced (any command can exit with status 127, if it calls `exit 127`).

Comment: If a process is killed by a signal, there is a secondary category. The  process does not return a code, but the kernel puts a code into the process table for the parent to retrieve. This will be 128 + the signal number (as listed by kill -l). e.g. SIGVIOL should be 139.